# Get name from textChange event in nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

have this code:

```
              <TextField
                v-model="lastname"
                @textChange="ontextChange"
                name="lastname"
              />
```

and i want get name from event:

```
ontextChange(args){
 console.log(args.name)
}
```

but i thing it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the wrong attribute in the arguments. It's of type [EventData](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/interfaces/_data_observable_.eventdata), you must be looking for `args.eventName`.

**Update:**

If you want to access the actual TextField which triggered the event, `args.object` should work.

Comment: solution: `args.object.name`

Comment: Sorry, your title confused me. I thought you were looking for the event name.

Comment: you can get the entered text as 

`let view = args.object;`
`let text=view.text;`